# Ajax not refreshing contact form

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms, contacts

I'm working on a site and the goal was to submit a contact form without reloading the whole page. I tried different paths, but nothing seems to help. It looks like the "on submit" part doesn't work at all I'm still leaving site to contact_form.php. I would be very thankful for any help, thanks in advance

This is js part:

```
$("#contact-form").on('submit', function(){
   var name = $("#form_name").val();
   var lastname = $("#form_lastname").val();
   var email = $("#form_email").val();
   var subject = $("#form_subject").val();
   var message = $("#form_message").val();

   var dataString = 'name=' + name + '&lastname=' + lastname + '&email=' + email +'&subject'+subject + '&message=' + message;
   $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "contact_form.php",
           data: dataString,
           cache: false,
           success: function(result){
                    alert(result);
                }
           });
        return false;
});
```

and here html:

```
<form id="contact-form" method="post" action="contact_form.php" role="form">
<div class="messages"></div>
    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input id="form_name" type="text" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" required="required"  data-invalid-message="Please enter your name">
                <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class ="form-row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input id="form_lastname" type="text" name="surname" class="form-control" placeholder="Last name" required="required" data-invalid-message="Please enter your name">
                <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input id="form_email" type="text" name="mail" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" required="required" data-invalid-message="Please enter your name">
                <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input id="form_subject" type="text" name="subject" class="form-control" placeholder="Subject" required="required" data-invalid-message="Please enter your name">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <textarea id="form_message" name="message" class="form-control" placeholder="Message" rows="4" required="required" data-invalid-message="Please enter your name"></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Send message">
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Remove action="contact_form.php" from form.

Comment: Need some basic debugging details added to question. Add a console or alert call in submit handler to see if it is actually being triggered. If it is...check actual request in browser dev tools network for status...what is sent, received etc. Should be using an error handler for the ajax also. If handler not being triggered does form actually exist at time you add the event listener? Without enough clues to narrow down the possibilities it is anyone's guess what is wrong

Comment: @charlietfl i guess it's not being triggered,  i added console.log at the beginning and nothing happend    $("#contact-form").on('submit', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log('test');

Comment: Is the code wrapped in a `document.ready` handler? Sounds like you are adding listener before form element exists

Comment: @charlietfl yes, here's the js code starts with $("document").ready(

function()
.... the rest of the code

Comment: Any ajax loading content like the form? What do you get with `console.log($("#contact-form").length)`? Should be 1 not 0. Also...any errors thrown in browser dev tools console? And shouldn't quote `document` it is a global object...`$(document)`

Answer (score 0):

You can start by passing the event and stopping the default behaviour, which would be to hit the action of the form.

```
$("#contact-form").on('submit', function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      // rest of code... ( do not return true in the end of this handler though )
```

Comment: `return false` that OP is using will also prevent default, assuming no errors occur before it gets to that point